# Why are there module options AND driver options - e.g. for the i915 module?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, drivers, kernel-modules

The `i915` Kernel module has several "module options" like the infamous `enable_rc6`.

However, for the `xorg` config file, there are further options such as `TearFree`.

I was wondering - why are there two ways to (seemingly?) set options the same module? Why can't I pass the `TearFree` option to the kernel module? Is this a general case and true for many other modules as well?

Any link to a good explanation is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they're two different drivers: the *kernel* driver and the *xorg* driver and each driver has its own, specific options.
The `i915` *kernel driver* talks to the hardware device (it does basic, low level stuff like set up resolution, map a framebuffer etc).
The *xorg* `intel` driver includes OpenGL, DRI, DDX etc for 2D/3D acceleration and communicates with the gpu via the kernel module. In fact, the `i915` [*kconfig*](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/Kconfig) even says

> This driver is used by the Intel driver in X.org 6.8 and XFree86 4.4
>   and above

---

Further reading:
[The Linux Graphics Stack](http://blog.mecheye.net/2012/06/the-linux-graphics-stack/)